# Parse Android Anonymous ParseUser not null but objectId is null

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using Parse to login using Facebook and also enabling Parse Anonymous User in the app. After logging out of the app, the ParseUser is not null but ParseUser.getObjectID() is returning null. The following is in onCreate() of Application.java

```
ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
ParseUser.getCurrentUser().increment("RunCount");
ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground();
```

Please help.

Comment: I am assuming since Parse uses objectIds for indexing items in their database, when you are only saving a ParseUser in the cache (it is an automatic user) there is no objectId given to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the documentation on Parse's docs for creating a new ParseUser:

> public ParseUser()
>
> > Constructs a new ParseUser with no data in it. A ParseUser constructed in this way will not have an objectId and will not persist to the database until ParseUser.signUp() is called.

So no objectId is attributed to this new ParseUser until you signUp, this means an automatic user doesn't have an objectId field (read my comment above).

To fix this, you can probably do something like:

```
ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
user.put("id", id);
...
...
user.saveInBackground();
```

since you are saving the new ParseUser to the local cache, it will have this id and is accessible. Not sure about your intentions to use the objectId, but it's always an option to create custom columns for a Parse object.